# Logical && and Logical || operator confusion

Tags: c

I found below code line in a opensource project:

```
if(WIFSTOPPED(status) && WSTOPSIG(status) == SIGTRAP)
```

I am not able to understand this code. According to code flow this should be(I am sure):

```
if((WIFSTOPPED(status) == SIGTRAP) || (WSTOPSIG(status) == SIGTRAP))
```

Are both the same??

Comment: From [this POSIX reference on `wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html): "`WIFSTOPPED(stat_val)` Evaluates to a non-zero value if status was returned for a child process that is currently stopped." In sort, it evaluates to a boolean value.

Comment: p v q (T v F) equates to T and p & q (F v T) equates to F, so they would not be equivalent. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_conjunction

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two code samples you offer are not the same. This

```
if (WIFSTOPPED(status) && WSTOPSIG(status) == SIGTRAP)
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (WIFSTOPPED(status) != 0 && WSTOPSIG(status) == SIGTRAP)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if (!(WIFSTOPPED(status) == 0 || WSTOPSIG(status) != SIGTRAP))
```

which is clearly different from:

```
if ((WIFSTOPPED(status) == SIGTRAP) || (WSTOPSIG(status) == SIGTRAP))
```

Do note also that the C operator precedence has `==` and `!=` as higher precedence than `&&` and `||`. Which means that the previous line of code is equivalent to:

```
if (WIFSTOPPED(status) == SIGTRAP || WSTOPSIG(status) == SIGTRAP)
```

The rules for logical operators that you need to know are:

```
!(a && b) == !a || !b
```

and

```
!(a || b) == !a && !b
```

Answer (score 2):

No, they're not the same.

`if(0)` is false in C, any other value considered to be true.

When you write:

```
if(WIFSTOPPED(status) && WSTOPSIG(status) == SIGTRAP)
```

Then if `WIFSTOPPED(status)` returns 0, the other side won't be evaluated due to [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

It's like writing:

```
if(WIFSTOPPED(status) != 0 && WSTOPSIG(status) == SIGTRAP)
```

---

[De-Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) should be very helpful for you:

- "not (A and B)" is the same as "(not A) or (not B)"
- "not (A or B)" is the same as "(not A) and (not B)"

Answer (score 0):

no they are not the same

the && means that both conditions must be true for the if statement to be true.

i dont know what WIFSTOPPED(status) does but in the second statement it doesnt have to equal SIGTRAP if (WSTOPSIG(status) equals SIGTRAP

while in the first statement  WIFSTOPPED(status) must return true AND  (WSTOPSIG(status) equals SIGTRAP

Answer (score 0):

Both are absolutely different.... First condition will apply when  WIFSTOPPED(status)==0 and
 WSTOPSIG(status) == SIGTRAP...   Second condition will apply when
  WIFSTOPPED(status) == SIGTRAP) or  (WSTOPSIG(status) == SIGTRAP)

Answer (score 0):

**That means** ::

In case `WIFSTOPPED` is bool:

```
if ( (WIFSTOPPED(status) != false) && *(WSTOPSIG(status) == SIGTRAP) )
```

In case `WIFSTOPPED is` string

```
if ( (WIFSTOPPED(status) != '') && *(WSTOPSIG(status) == SIGTRAP) )
```

In case `WIFSTOPPED` is integer:

```
if ( (WIFSTOPPED(status) != 0) && *(WSTOPSIG(status) == SIGTRAP) )
```